# Why does history require a numeric value for grep?

Tags: bash, function, history

I am trying to make a custom function (hisgrep) to grep from history.

I had it working before, when the code was basically "history | grep $1", but I want the implementation to be able to grep multiple keywords. (e.g. "hisgrep docker client" would equal "history | grep docker | grep client").

My problem is that, when I try to do this I get this error: "-bash: history: |: numeric argument required."

I've tried changing how the command was called in the end from `$cmd` to just $cmd, but that did nothing.

Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

function hisgrep() {
    cmd='history'
    for arg in "$@"; do
        cmd="$cmd | grep $arg"
    done
    `$cmd`
}
```

Comment: `eval "$cmd"` has a chance of working (but add `grep "$1"`…`grep "$<n>"` instead of `grep <arg>` to the command)

Comment: @Ry- But wouldn't that make it so I have to know how many arguments it will recieve always?

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/050](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, bash doesn't have something called "foldl" or similar function.

You can do it like this:

```
histgrep() {
    local str;
    # save the history into some list
    # I already filter the first argument, so the initial list is shorter
    str=$(history | grep -e "$1");
    shift;
    # for each argument
    for i; do
       # pass the string via grep
       str=$(<<<"$str" grep "$i")
    done
    printf "%s\n" "$str"
}
```

Notes:

- Doing `cmd="$cmd | grep $arg"` and then doing `$cmd` looks unsafe.
- Remember to quote your variables.
- Use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check your scripts.
- Backticks ` are [deprecated](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete). Use `$()` command substitution.
- using both function and parenthesis `function func()` is not portable. Just do `func()`.

As for the unsafe version, you need to pass it via eval (and `eval` is [`evil`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)), which by smart using `printf` shortens to just:

```
histgrep() { eval "history $(printf "| grep -e '%s' " "$@")"; }
```

But I think we can do a lot safer by expanding the arguments after command substitution, inside the `eval` call:

```
histgrep() { eval "history $(printf '| grep -e "$%s" ' $(seq $#))"; }
```

The `eval` here will see `history | grep -e "$1" | grep -e "$2" | ...` which I think looks actually quite safe.

Comment: How about a manual fold? `multigrep() { if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then cat; else local p="$1"; shift; grep -e "$p" | multigrep "$@"; fi; }`, then `history | multigrep foo bar`.

Comment: Recursive looks nice. You can even not abuse cat's with `multigrep() { if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then grep "$@"; else ...`

Comment: Wouldn't that break `multigrep` (with no arguments)?

Comment: With the `eval` approaches, one could also attempt to properly quote the arguments. Either using `"${@@Q}"`, resulting in `histgrep() { eval "history $(printf '| grep -e %s' "${@@Q}")"; }`, or using `printf '%q'` (if POSIX is not a requirement), resulting in `histgrep() { eval "history $(printf '| grep -e %q' "$@")"; }`.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because `|` is interpreted as an argument to the `history` command.